# Телеграм бот. Ошибка сертификата

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Я создал своего бота. Выбрал метод Webhook. Подключил, указал рабочий сертификат. Теперь пишу боту, он молчит. Посмотрел инфу через getWebhookInfo. А там:

```
{
   "ok":true,
   "result":{
        "url":"https://путь_до_файла.php",
        "has_custom_certificate":true,
        "pending_update_count":5,
        "last_error_date":1508481212,
        "last_error_message":"SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
        "max_connections":40
    }
}
```

Что я не так делаю?`

Comment: Попробуй другой сертификат установить. Не подходит твой, как видишь. Если сервер на `Apache`, есть `Certbot` для установки бесплатного сертификата от `Let's Encrypt`.

Comment: да, из за сертификата не работал, сейчас все ок. спасибо что откликнулись